# What is the "Development Assets" feature introduced in Xcode 11 and how to use it?

Tags: ios, xcode, assets, xcode11, ipados

When I examined settings of a target in Xcode 11.1 (accessed when clicking on a project in the Project navigator sidebar and then clicking on an executable target), I noticed a new expandable section called "Development Assets", which wasn't present in Xcode 10. I also can't find any documentation about it or mentions in release notes.

[image: Development Assets section]

Has anyone discovered yet what's the purpose of this section, what's the best use case for it, how to use it, and maybe some documentation written either by Apple or anyone in the community?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's a way of adding assets to your project that won't be delivered in production but will be available during development.  This includes Asset catalogs and other resources.  As mentioned these won't be added to the app bundle when the project is *Archived*.

See [WWDC 2019 *Mastering Xcode Previews*](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/233/).

Comment: Assets I added to "Development Assets" still appeared in my "release" build, but were eventually removed when using Product > Archive.